# How can I create a new list when giving intergers, and have to return hexadecimal

Tags: python, list, hex

Given the following list:
`list = [2,10,10,10,4,5]`

How can I write a function that returns the output:
`output = 210AA:45`

I was working with this code so far, but don't know what else to add so that once a number between 10 and 15 is repeated, return the repeated number in its hexadecimal form as in the output

```
def int_to_string(data): 
    string = ""
    for i in data: 
        hexadecimal = hex(i)
        string += hexadecimal[2:]
        string[0] = 15
    return string
```

Comment: where is from `:` in your output?

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary describing the mapping between decimal and hex could add readability.

Remark: don't shadow the name of build-functions, in this case `list`. See [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) for a complete list.

```
lst = [2,10,10,10,4,5,13,15,0] # <- new testing list

# dictionary for conversion
num2hex = {i: str(i) for i in range(10)}
num2hex.update(zip(range(10, 16), "ABCDEF")) 

# conversion list -> str
res = ''
consecutve_hex, is_last_hex = 0, False
for d in lst:
    if 10 <= d <= 15:
        consecutive_hex += 1
        is_last_hex = False
        if consecutive_hex > 1:
            res += num2hex[d]
        else:
            res += str(d)
    else:
        if not is_last_hex:
            if res:
                res += ':'
        consecutive_hex = 0 
        is_last_hex = True
        res += str(d)

print(res)
#210AA:4513F:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list `[]` instead of a string `""`
strings are immutable and don't support index lookup and assignment.
append the hex val and then edit the first index as you see fit to get your result
and retun a joined list with
`''.join(#ur_lst)`